# How to convert an array in an complex array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this `array` `[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

I want if the sum of the values exceed four, it's make a new array in array.

I want a result like that: `[[2,1],[2,1,1],[1,1,1]]`

Comment: i dont get the logical rule..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and use it for adding the values of the last inserted array and for the whole result array.

The main part of the algorithm is this line

```
!i || r[r.length - 1].reduce(add, 0) + a > 4 ?
    r.push([a]) :
    r[r.length - 1].push(a);
```

In it, a check takes place, if `i` is zero (at start) or if the sum of the last array of the result is in sum with the actual item greater than 4, then a new array with the actual value is added. If not, then the element is pushed to the last array.

```js
var data = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    add = function (a, b) { return a + b; },
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        !i || r[r.length - 1].reduce(add, 0) + a > 4 ? r.push([a]) : r[r.length - 1].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, I see your solution, very elegant +1

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and build a new one, if the sum exceed 4 push the previous array into the result like:

```
var myArr = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

var newArr = [];
var newInner = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  if (summArr(newInner) + myArr[i] > 4) {
    newArr.push(newInner);
    newInner = [];
  }
  newInner.push(myArr[i]);
  if (i==myArr.length-1) newArr.push(newInner);
}

function summArr(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(add, 0);

  function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q0ps7960/

Answer (score 0):

for simple way...

```js
var array1 = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
 var tmp=[];
 var output=[];
 var sum=0;
  for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
   sum +=array1[i];
   if(sum<=4){
    tmp.push(array1[i]);
   }else{
    output.push(tmp);
    sum =array1[i];
    tmp=[array1[i]];
   }
  }
  output.push(tmp);
console.log(output);
```